# Does Financial Modeling Prep API have a rate limit?

Tags: api, finance, stock

I'm looking at Financial Modeling Prep API: https://financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs/

This API is really cool since it provides almost everything I'm looking for. However, details about different pricing plans are not that detailed.

For the free plan, it says 250 requests but doesn't mention any rate limits. Are these requests per month, year, or after 250 requests, I no longer can make requests?

For other plans, it says unlimited requests but similarly doesn't mention rate limits.

I also don't know where to check how many requests I've made on Financial Modeling Prep.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Oh by the way, if anyone has better stock APIs with suitable prices for students, please tell me!

Comment: I would recommend contacting the support. A small rule of thumb, if no rate limits are listed; then there are no limits.

Comment: I have contacted the support for 2 days. I guess I just have to wait a little longer. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @AnhTuDo did you get an answer from them?

Comment: @milanDD Yes. 1: For the free plan, 250 requests are the total number of requests you can use. It's not per month or per year. After using all 250 requests, you need to switch to another plan. 2: There are no rate limits. Only for parallels queries, they limit to 4 per second. But you can contact them to remove this limit. 3: To know the number of requests you've made using API, you can contact their support and ask directly. 4: Asking them through their Facebook will get you answers much quicker!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those who have the same questions as me, here is the answer:

1: For the free plan, 250 requests are the total number of requests you can use. It's not per month or per year. After using all 250 requests, you need to switch to another plan.

2: There are no rate limits. Only for parallels queries, they limit to 4 per second. But you can contact them to remove this limit.

3: To know the number of requests you've made using API, you can contact their support and ask directly.

4: Asking them through their Facebook will get you answers much quicker!